# convert 12V PWM circuit to 5V PWM using opamp

Tags: operational-amplifier, pwm, level-shifting

I can convert a 12 V PWM signal into 5V signal, by using voltage divider on 12 volt signal , then directing it to base of NPN common emitter transistor with collector connected to 5V

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fn2crA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

How can i do same using Op amp ?

Comment: It is possible to do it but beware of slew rate. If the pwm is too fast, the signal will no longer be square like.

Comment: The main issue with this circuit is that it inverts the signal. So a 10% PWM signal at 12V becomes a 90% signal at 5V.

Comment: This site has a integrated schematic editor.  Use it.  ASCII art need not apply.

Comment: Depending upon what you're doing with the signal, an op-amp is probably NOT what you want to be using.  There are dynamic considerations, and more limitations on the output current than good approaches.

Comment: Yes it's possible. You make a voltage divider on your MCU pin, and put the opamp in a box where you keep stuff for your future projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends upon your PWM frequency and the shortest mark/space pulses resulting from the nearest PWM positions to 0 % and 100 %.

This would carry out the general function:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fX5zRB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The op-amp's '-' input is held at 2.5 V (half of 5 V).

The op-amp's '+' input switches between 0 V and around 4 V (about a third of 12 V, more precisely 3.8 V).

You will have to choose a suitable op-amp for your PWM frequency. If your PWM frequency is too high or the mark/space pulses too short, R1 and R2 should be lowered to ensure a fast rise/fall time at the op-amp pins while charging/discharging the stray capacitance there.

Comment: is it non inverting op-amp configuration ?

Comment: what will be the gain formula for this ? .. Also if it is noninverting amplifier then o/p should connect to the feedback resistor like in this link http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_3.html but you are connecting Rf=R3 to 5V ?

Comment: @user6363, it's open-loop, there is no feedback. Can you post fully-formed questions or conclusions rather than just bits of thinking, please :-)

Comment: Thanks for reply.. I want to know how output will be 5V when i/p applied will be 12V ..? as per this link http://nptel.ac.in/courses/Webcourse-contents/IIT-ROORKEE/Analog%20circuits/lecturers/lecture_8/lecture8_page1.htm .. it seems your circuit is .. open loop differential amplifier  .. and its o/p is vo = Ad (vin1 – vin2 ) .. where Ad will be open loop gain .. so for your circuit it will be vo = Ad(3.8 - 2.5) .. so what is value of Ad for this op amp .. that o/p will be 5V ?

Comment: @user6363, it's being used as a comparator. Try searching google for 'op-amp as a comparator' or read www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/AN-849.pdf

Comment: Ok thanks got the concept ..  ... http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/op-amp-comparator.html

Comment: you also mentioned in your answer "R1 and R2 should be lowered to ensure a fast rise/fall time " here if frequency of PWM is high then how value of R1 & R2 will affect the rise & fall time ? can you bit explain this ?

Comment: Just not a great idea.  Not only do you have to find an op amp that's fast enough, you have to find one that can output all the way to the positive rail, and not lock up.

Comment: @scottseidman, fast enough? Have you read the answer text. Rail to rail op-amp.

Comment: You know about rail to rail op-amps, I know about them, but the asker probably doesn't.   R1 and R2 will not have much to do with the op-amps speed and output slew.   Further, a complete answer likely to help the asker must include some pointer to output current requirements.  The approach asked for is just not a very robust approach, and any answers should reflect that.

Comment: Note that you're also saturating the op amp at rail, and need to pay attention to lock up issues.  Op amps just don't make very good comparators.

Comment: @ScottSeidman, they make perfectly good comparators for many applications. The OP asked for an op-amp circuit, not a redesign, and there it is. This circuit will work perfectly well for a low enough PWM frequency and my answer tells them to pay attention to this. The OP hasn't stated a PWM frequency. Could be LEDs at 100 Hz. If OP is experimenting and breadboarding this up, my answer lets them get on, try and revise. I will revise my answer as they ask and develop, as I always do. Looks like you assumed they've got 10'skHz of PWM, need your redesign and and dished out downvotes accordingly.

Comment: Just one DV in the thread, so I'm not "dishing them out".   I normally wouldn't DV an op amp used as a comparator, but this design depends upon which op-amp is used (though not for speed, as indicated in the answer),  how close the particular op amp can get to the rail on output, and overstating the impact of R1 and R2 on the speed of the circuit.  If you went through the exercise of showing the op-amp selection process with  a good choice and a bad choice, and included info about what freq range this would work in, it might even get an upvote.

Comment: ... and revenge DV's are sort of de classe

Comment: @ScottSeidman, sounds like you want it justified to your satisfaction rather than suitable for the OP. Anyway, you're sort of like a dog with a postman's leg and a little aimless. This is beyond comment, go to chat if you like otherwise let's leave it there and I'll wish you well.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple circuit to get the job done. You can use a simple voltage divider followed by a buffer.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNvn5Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Choose the op-amp, R1 and R2 to suit your application's requirements. I have chosen R1 = 1K, R2 = 1.5K. When the input is 12V, the output is 4.8V. You may find more suitable values to get 5V on the output.

If you use 5V to power the op-amp you may not get 4.8V on the output because op-amp output voltage is never the same as the op-amp supply voltage. Using 12V supply for the op-amp can give you better results.

Answer (score 2):

Many circuit using opamp can fit your need. There is some point you have to consider :

- The original circuit on your post change the polarity of the PWM (70% duty become 30% duty cycle PWM)
- Opamp have slew rate, this mean, at high frequency, the PWM's waveform may change. Choose your part wisely ;)

Answer (score 0):

> How can i do same using Op amp ?

One inverting amp will do. Or two inverting amps if you want to maintain the same polarity.

But there are much simpler ways for you to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If all you are doing is feeding the attenuated signal to an Arduino digital port then just use a resistor potential divider: -

[image]

Let's say you make R2 = 1 kohm, then R1 has to be 7/5 * 1 kohm = 1.4 kohm

You might choose to make R1 = 1.5 kohm (in case the 12 volt rises a little bit). Check your logic high levels on the Arduino to see how high R1 could be before it fails to register a logic one when 12 volts is at the input.

For instance, a lot of IOs are TTL compatible meaning that 2 volts is the minimum logic 1 so, make a potential divider from 12 volts to 3 volts. This would make R1 = 1.8 kohm.

Using fairly low resistance values means rise and fall times will be largely unaffected at the output (unlike an op-amp or a comparator which will likely worsen the rise times and add a delay). Stay simple if you can.

Comment: You really should explain why this won't work well if it is NOT being used to simply drive an Arduino digital port.

Comment: @ScottSeidman the op shows it connecting to such a port and my words in my answer were reinforcing this. It will work well in the situation and many situations but to generalise situations where it won't work well is perhaps going too far.

Comment: Concern isn't for this poster, but for other beginners who try to use your fine solution in a situation where it isn't so fine.  It's an error I see all the time, and probably worth a sentence to help novices avoid it.